# Stopping a multiprocesses after a certain period if it's still alive

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using the multiprocess package for Python I'm setting up 20 workers for content scraping of .pdf files. It works like this:

1. I pass a list of paths of files to the function
2. The function checks which documents has already been scraped and which haven't
3. The function begins scraping the missing documents
4. The function moves on to the next path

However, for some files the process stalls and simply hangs for hours. I want to set a timer such that the process is terminated and it moves on to the next document / path.

Right now I'm doing the following:

## spin up processes

```
queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
lock = mp.Lock()

for file, path in files_scrape.items():
    queue.put((path, dest_path))


jobs_remaining = queue.qsize()
pbar = tqdm(position = 0, total=jobs_remaining)

consumers = []
for i in range(n_workers):
    p = mp.Process(target = textract_worker,
                   args = (lock, queue, i))
    p.daemon = True
    consumers.append(p)

for p in consumers:
    p.start()


while jobs_remaining > 0:
    tmp = queue.qsize()
    pbar.update(jobs_remaining - tmp)
    jobs_remaining = tmp
```

After searching for similar problems I found the following snippit which I tried adding to my code:

```
for p in consumers:
    p.start()
    p.join(10)
    if p.is_alive():
        print('function terminated')
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

However, the result of this seems to be that the process simply waits for 10 seconds, then shuts down even though there are no documents to scrape in the path. Also this happens one by one due to the loop. I've also tried passing the .join() and .is_alive() functions in a separate loop after all processes has been started but that nets a similar result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the **Warning** about using [Process.terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate). ***"stalls and simply hangs for hours"***: Try to use `timeout` at this point!

Comment: @stovfl Thanks for the heads up, I've changed the terminate call to .close() but it still isn't working as intended. What do you mean regarding "Try to use timeout at this point!" ?

Comment: ***"stalls and simply hangs for hours"***: This sould be happen in `textract_worker`, find this **"stalls"** call and verify if it's possible to set a `timeout`.

Comment: @stovfl yes I certain its happening in the textract.process() call inside the worker function, problem is it doesn't break or return any errors, it just keeps "processing" which is why I want to interrupt the worker / process if it's been running for more than say 20 seconds

Comment: You use `lock, queue` inside `textract_worker`, both are candidates for deadlock. [Edit] your question and show the code.